# Join and format a resultset

Tags: mysql, select, join, pivot-table

Hello please help me with a problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.titulo as 'Periodicas', B.titulo as 'No periodicas'
FROM publicacion A, Publicacion B, periodicas
WHERE A.idPublicacion=periodicas.Publicacion_idPublicacion
AND B.idPublicacion NOT IN (SELECT periodicas.Publicacion_idPublicacion FROM periodicas)
```

I want to separate periodicals and non-periodical publications .

```
+--------------+---------------+
| Periodicas   | No periodicas |
+------+-------+---------------+
| Publica 1    | Publica 5     |
| Publica 2    | Publica 5     |
| Publica 3    | Publica 5     |
| Publica 4    | Publica 5     |
+--------------+---------------+
```

As I have only one publication that is "No periodica" is repeated every time. Eh tested using DISTINCT but I can not do that only display once.

Data:

Table "Publicacion"

```
+---------------+---------------+
| idPublicacion | titulo        |
+---------------+---------------+
| 1             | Publica 1     |
| 2             | Publica 2     |
| 3             | Publica 3     |
| 4             | Publica 4     |
| 5             | Publica 5     |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Table Periodicas:

```
+--------------+---------------------------+
| idPeriodica  | Publicacion_idPublicacion |
+------+-------+---------------------------+
| 10           |         1                 |
| 11           |         2                 |
| 12           |         3                 |
| 13           |         4                 |
+--------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: you're joining 3 tables, but only have conditions for two of the joins, so you're getting a partial cartesian product. re-write using prop `JOIN` and provide a join condition for all of the tables.

Comment: it looks like a self-join one minute then not the next. i don't see output possible in one row. can you at least provide some sample data

Comment: join is faulty, no sample data to understand periodical vs non-periodical, no schema provided. the above is really poor sample data

Comment: I put my data tables

Comment: show the create table statements of the 2 or 3 tables and describe the columns so we can answer the question

Comment: Don't use "comma-JOIN", use `JOIN ... ON...`.  Don't use `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`; switch to either `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ... )` or `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do something perfectly natural, that is categorize rows of one table according to their presence in another table.

But you're also trying to do something unnatural in the SQL way of thinking, and that is to organize a report horizontally rather than vertically. In most cases you'd do that in a report program rather than in SQL.

Here's a query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ff57/8/0) that will do the first part of your project.

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN b.titulo IS NULL THEN 'No Periodico' ELSE 'Periodico' END tipo,
       a.idPublicacion,
       b.idPeriodica,
       a.titulo
 FROM  Pub a
 LEFT JOIN Per b ON a.titulo = b.titulo
```

The second part is unreasonably hard in MySQL. You need to do an operation called a pivot. The problem is that you have no natural way to laminate together your periodicals and non-periodicals.